# MATLAB: HMM + kmeans + ST

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means, hidden-markov-models

I'm working on a NILM algorithm for school project.

I have a database with sampled (1024samples/cycle) transient of various current signals.
I'm gonna train my HMMs with feature vector extracted from the Stockwell Transform but I need help.

1) The Stockwell Transform of 1024 time samples is a matrix 1024*1024. After that I create a matrix 10*1024 choosing the first 10 harmonics (f0, 2*f0,..,10*f0).

Now I need to create a feature vector for the HMM. I'd like to use the kmeans algorithm to create a vector of 1024 symbols but my elements are complex numers so kmeans isn't working well.
I could make two feature vector: one for the absolute part and one for the imaginary but then how I train my Hmm with two vector for observation?

2) Correct me if I'm wrong: in the hmm, each row of the observation matrix is a sequence, so in my case my obs. matrix is a n*1024 matrix where n is the number of transient of the same type that I've got in my database, isn't it?

Thank you.

Comment: K-means for matlab only work for real values, perhaps you want to use abs(value), since the abs gives you the magnitude of your transform while angle(value) gives you the phase info. so you can train your HMM with magnitude + phase information clustered using K-means (perhaps consider a Gaussian Mixture Model?).

Comment: In Matlab HMM i.e. [estTR,estE] = hmmtrain(seq,A,PO,'Pseudotransitions',Pseudo);
seq is the sequence of observation (i.e. good, bad, average) [seq(integers), 3 possible observations = 1 or 2 or 3], A [State x State] is the initial transition matrix which you can random initialize if you have no idea of the structure of the hidden states. PO is the initial observation probability matrix [State x possible observations]. you can use or delete 'pseudo' base on how much knowledge you have on the hidden states and how confident you are with your PO

Comment: Ok, I could divide my transform in magnitude and phase and then cluster this two matrix but then I'll get two sequence vector, not one. I need one sequence vector for each observation to train the hmm.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I was getting at, the Matlab HMM only lets sequence, but not distributions. You can try to cleverly combine the observations into one sequence.

Comment: I'm not using the matlab hmm, but this toolbox [link](http://nuweb.neu.edu/bbarbiellini/CBIO3580/HW7.html). Is it possible with this?

Comment: Ah yes, this is the well known version that works for multiple types of input. The heart of your question lies in what you want to model, the magnitude, the phase or both, and in what form, a distribution or a series of discrete values. Let us say that you collect current signals under a controlled fashion, which resulted in particular magnitude and phase/direction, you have to ask yourself is this behaviour static, or is it a distribution that can be measured by a mean and variance (more likely). This allows you to cluster/model your observation for this particular set-up.

Comment: Having the distribution of magnitude and phase for each possible set-up then allows you to start training your model. Say your problem is something like "this magnitude and phase pattern was just detected, what is the most likely set-up that caused this?" You can (supervise) train your HMM by first identifying for each state(set-up) what are the distributions of magnitude and phase respectively. Once you have this, you can run a series of observation to train the transition matrix automatically. The logic is that the HMM sees changes in magnitude and phase, interpret this to change in set-up.

Comment: If you let the HMM see enough observations (your sequence), it will train the Transition matrix along with the probability of seeing each particular sequence in that state (i.e. Observation Probability Matrix). Once you have a trained HMM, you can then track on to the states using a simple Viterbi, or whichever you prefer. Your Observation should be a joint distribution of Magnitude and Phase information expressed, perhaps, in the form of a mean and a covariance, depending on what algorithm you chose to cluster them.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot for your explanation. So, if I would treat it like a distribution, how to proceed to calculate mean and variance?

Comment: Do you have readings of the current? you can statistically compute the mean and variance, alternatively, use a model to compute them (i.e. GMM or even K-means), and generate a distribution that you think is logical (be it Gaussian or Linear etc. I would imagine it to be Gaussian).

Comment: Yes, I've got readings. So I'll try to use GMM and then, use the MHMM function in the toolbox, right?

Comment: GMM is a good choice, which type of HMM to use is up to you, have fun :D !